# Prevent injection attack form Redcarpet gem in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redcarpet

I have a text area that allows user to type in description of their cars.

It is saved as :text and when called, I will render via the ApplicationHelper as below:

```
module ApplicationHelper
    def markdown(text)
        renderer = Redcarpet::Render::HTML
        @engine = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(renderer, 
            hard_wrap: true,
            filter_html: true,
            autolink: true,
            no_intra_emphasis: true
        )
        @engine.render(text)
    end
end
```

Being paranoia, I tried typing in something like this in my textarea.

```
Markdown.

__Nice.__

<%= @car %>
<script>
  alert('damn');
</script>
```

While the `<%= @car %>` did not parse in to ruby code, but the script was indeed executed.

In my view:

```
<%= markdown(@car.description).html_safe %>
```

I wonder if it is the right way handling with redcarpet;  is this mechanism prone to any attack,  and how can I prevent it?

Best

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm stuck on the same issue.. Thanks!